# Datagrid columns contains value

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm working application in C#, .NET.

How can I check in DataGridView component if some columns contains specific value?
I have some contains methods, but I don't know how I would use them..

Comment: Looks like your missing some of the question text, can you edit your question to include whatever is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
    {
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)e.Row.DataItem;
        if (row["yourColumnName"] == "YourDesiredValue")
            row["yourColumnName"] = "changevalue";
    }
}
```

You can find and change value of column(s)

Answer (score 2):

If I am correct then you want Column value not RowCell Value, and its in Windows app.

You can loop through each column in datagridview

Like..

```
        foreach (var GridColumn in DataGridView1.Columns )
        {
             //get value from column
         }
```

For Rows,

```
       foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows )
        {
            if(item.Cells["Column Name"].Value==your condition)
                //her you got the cell to work with

        }
```

You can use LINQ for same

Comment: I just want to search if one column (I already know which it is) contains specific value ...

Comment: And then I want to update cell in this row, where value was found.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can act directly on the datasource, if it is datatable, dataset, list ..

You have methods to do that on all data collections types..

Comment: I just have dataGridView .. I want to check if some column already contains value, then in the row where this value was found I want to update another cell ..

Comment: Ya, just ensure you binded your data with Grid.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(Datagridviewrow item in datagridview1.rows)
{
    if(item.cell[indexNumber].value.tostring().contains("your word"));
    {
        messagebox.show("contains")
    }
    else
    {
        messagebox.show("NOT contains")
    }
}
```